# An alternative approach to proving the Carnot's theorem using the equality of areas of $pV$ and $TS$ diagrams

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

According to Carnot's theorem, the efficiency of a reversible heat engine operating between two reservoirs at different temperatures is independent of the working substance and depends only on the temperatures of the reservoirs. The efficiency is given by:
$$
\eta = 1 - \frac{T_L}{T_H}
$$
where $T_L$ and $T_H$ are the absolute temperatures of the low-temperature and high-temperature reservoirs, respectively. This is the highest efficiency  any heat engine can achieve.

The area enclosed by the cycle on the PV diagram represents the net work done by the engine, while the area enclosed by the cycle on the TS diagram represents the net heat absorbed by the engine. For a reversible cycle, these two areas are equal, because of the first law of thermodynamics:
$$
W = Q_H - Q_L
$$
where $W$ is the net work done, $Q_H$ is the heat absorbed from the high-temperature reservoir, and $Q_L$ is the heat rejected to the low-temperature reservoir.

The efficiency of a heat engine can also be expressed as:
$$
\eta = \frac{W}{Q_H} = 1 - \frac{Q_L}{Q_H}
$$

To prove Carnot's theorem using the equality of areas in PV and TS diagrams, we can start by considering a Carnot cycle, which is a reversible thermodynamic cycle operating between two reservoirs at different temperatures.

1. PV Diagram: The area enclosed by the Carnot cycle on the PV diagram represents the net work done by the engine ($W$).
2. TS Diagram: The area enclosed by the Carnot cycle on the TS diagram represents the net heat absorbed by the engine, which is the difference between the heat absorbed from the high-temperature reservoir ($Q_H$) and the heat rejected to the low-temperature reservoir ($Q_L$).

By the first law of thermodynamics, we have $W = Q_H - Q_L$. Therefore, the equality of the areas on the PV and TS diagrams can be expressed as:
$$
\text{{Area in PV diagram}} = W = Q_H - Q_L = \text{{Area in TS diagram}}
$$

Now, let's express the efficiency of the Carnot engine using the heat quantities:
$$
\eta = \frac{W}{Q_H} = \frac{Q_H - Q_L}{Q_H} = 1 - \frac{Q_H}{Q_L}
$$

Since the Carnot engine is reversible, it operates between two reservoirs at temperatures $T_H$ (high-temperature reservoir) and $T_L$ (low-temperature reservoir). According to Carnot's theorem, the efficiency only depends on the temperatures of the reservoirs, not the specific working substance. Therefore, we can rewrite $Q_L$ and $Q_H$ in terms of the temperatures:
$$
\frac{Q_L}{Q_H} = \frac{T_L}{T_H}
$$

Substituting this into the expression for efficiency, we get:
$$
\eta = 1 - \frac{T_L}{T_H} = 1 - \frac{T_L}{T_H}.
$$

This confirms Carnot's theorem, which states that the efficiency of a reversible heat engine operating between two reservoirs at different temperatures is independent of the working substance and depends only on temperatures of its hot and cold reservoirs.

What do you think of this proof? Is it correct and could the Carnot's theorem be proven in this, is this proof sufficient?

Comment: I don't see anything unique about your "proof".

Comment: You are, in many places, assuming the result you needed to prove. You should note that back when introducing all these things, basically none of the stuff were established. For example, 1st law was barely accepted, $W=Q_H-Q_L$ had to be established, and especially why should $Q_L$ be there. Equality of areas had to be proved. The heats $Q$ depend upon the size of the engine, so it is not immediately obvious that $Q_L/Q_H=T_L/T_H$. Everything had to be established from scratch, and so it is nowhere near as easy as what you are trying to do.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the answers!